# Windows 11 - Disabled sound output device keeps reappearing

Tags: windows, audio, windows-11

I have two sound output devices I want: headphones and speakers.

My problem is that I have a third sound output device that keeps popping up even though I disabled it: The monitor. It will show up again on restart after a few days to a week.

[image: Picture of available sound output devices on my computer. Shows headphones, speakers and monitor. Monitor sound output device is undesired.]

**How can I permanently prevent this sound output device from reappearing in the sound output menu in the task bar?**

---

I've tried **Don't Allow** in the Sound system settings. That doesn't work.

[image: Sound System setting for the monitor sound. Shows the Don't Allow button that is not a permanent solution to preventing this device from being used as a sound output.]

---

I've tried **disabling**, **uninstalling** the monitor sound device in the **device manager**. That also doesn't work.

[image: Device manager showing "Audio Input and outputs". Right click menu for the monitor sound. Shows disable and uninstall device (amongst other non-relevant) options.]

---

I've tried looking in the nVidia Control Panel for any options regarding sound but that just takes me to the Control Panel Sound options which are covered below.

[image: nVidia Control Panel. Display -> Set up digital audio. Shows no actual options for sound.]

---

I've tried **disabling** the sound output device from the **Control Panel -> Hardware and Sound -> Sound -> Playback menu**. That also doesn't work.

[image: Control Panel -> Hardware and Sound -> Sound -> Playback menu.]

---

I was able to find the event log for this monitor audio. The weird thing is some of the times are in the future not just for my time zone but also UTC. **This event log shows that device install was requested. I don't know by whom, but it wasn't me. How can I stop this?**

[image: Event viewer log under Control Panel -> Hardware and Sound -> Sound -> Playback -> Select monitor audio -> Properties -> General -> Controller Information -> Events]

From the event viewer, **`oem27.inf`** **is the file used to configure the audio for the monitor**. Here are the file contents https://hastebin.com/share/wekimejexo.perl

```
Device HDAUDIO\FUNC_01&VEN_10DE&DEV_0092&SUBSYS_38422182&REV_1001\5&599fd6c&0&0001 was configured.

Driver Name: oem27.inf
Class Guid: {4d36e96c-e325-11ce-bfc1-08002be10318}
Driver Date: 01/19/2023
Driver Version: 1.3.40.14
Driver Provider: NVIDIA Corporation
Driver Section: WIN11NVHDA64V
Driver Rank: 0xFF2005
Matching Device Id: HDAUDIO\FUNC_01&VEN_10DE&DEV_0092
Outranked Drivers: oem7.inf:HDAUDIO\FUNC_01&VEN_10DE&DEV_0092:00FF2005 hdaudio.inf:HDAUDIO\FUNC_01:00FF300C
Device Updated: true
Parent Device: PCI\VEN_10DE&DEV_10F8&SUBSYS_21823842&REV_A1\4&2283f625&0&0119
```

Comment: Am I allowed to share the event viewer log .evtx file? How do I upload it?

Comment: The problem is that turning off the monitor will uninstall the device, and turning it on will install it again. See if the monitor itself has a setting to either disable the audio or an energy setting such that it is not uninstalled after turning the device off, or the GPU has a setting to disable audio from there.

Comment: @Vader - Post the relevant information from the event by typing it into the body. There is no upload capability for SE communities

Comment: Try in *Settings > System > Sound* to click "Manage sound devices", click on "GZS7HU (NVIDIA High Def‌inition Audio)" and then on "Disable". See if it's re-enabled after reboot.

Comment: I don't see  "Manage sound devices" https://i.imgur.com/9lOodOX.png

Comment: Windows 11 just had to rename everything. It's now called "All sound devices" and you already found it. Try to [Disable Sound Output Device in Device Manager](https://www.elevenforum.com/t/enable-or-disable-sound-output-device-in-windows-11.16126/#Three). If it doesn't work, you might as last-ditch effort use the old-time trick of replacing its driver by a non-sound driver that in effect will totally sabotage the device. (Add to your comment `@harrymc` for me to be notified.)